# How to fetch the List View Id through custom Button in List view Layout?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, list-view, lightninglistview

I have a custom object with a Assessment__C (API Name ) and I have two ListViews: week1 and Week2 .Now, I need to fetch the List View Id and pass it to the LWC to perform some action because I have some requirements regarding the List View Id. Does anyone have any ideas or solutions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  What have you tried and where are you stuck?  Please [edit] your post to include your work you have done and the specific problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the CurrentPageReference to retrieve the URL parameters that contain the List View Id.

The state attribute of the page reference let's you retrieve the paramaters.

Example (to be transparent, I haven't tested this yet sorry):

```
 import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
 import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
    
    export default class Test extends LightningElement {
    
        listViewId = null;

        @wire(CurrentPageReference)
        getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
           if (currentPageReference) {
              this.urlStateParameters = currentPageReference?.state?.filterName;
           }
        }
    }
```

Example and more explanation available here: https://beyondthecloud.dev/blog/get-url-parameters-in-lwc

Comment: Hi Callum MacErlich,

Thank you for your quick response. However, my requirement is to place the button in the List View layout using a custom button on that particular object. Whenever I click this button, it should fetch the List View ID and pass this ID to the LWC component where I can retrieve the respective records of the List View and store all the records in the Array and send  a Email to my Manager Email with these Records.

But I was stuck to get the List View Id using Custom Button in the List view Layout and pass this List View Id to the LWC ?


Any other solution please?

Comment: Hi @NarendranR, I've updated my answer now